# Creating highly formatted PDF forms using BIRT - e.g. Tax Documents

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, birt

I'm using open-source BIRT and trying to generate government forms, like W-2s or 1099s (http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw2.pdf). These have government-mandated positions for text and grids, so that they're machine-readable. We currently use background images of the form layout and then lay the text over the form, but this yields high file sizes (multiple MBs) and doesn't seem optimal. Any ideas how to best accomplish this? Are there any repositories for this type of file (the rptdesign)? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output type of your reports. I have done PDFs and they are usually not too big. If the images are heavy (multiple MBs), the file can be huge.. Try to reduce their size if possible

Comment: We're outputting PDFs. I've looked into a few things, like taking the government-provided PDFs (which is what we show as a background image) and converting them to XML and then splicing that into the report design (I couldn't get it to work). I did have some luck with converting the PDF to SVG and importing them that way - a good maount smaller.

Comment: If you remove all the images .. what is the file size with and without them ?

Comment: @SaurabhSinghal its a difference (as currently implemented) of ~50kb to several MB, since we had been using png images. SVG gets that down to < 400kb w/ image. I think that might be the solution instead of trying to re-create the forms ourselves.

Comment: You could reduce the image size by reducing its resolution.. which would not affect the out put of the same in the form. Either try to reduce the image size say from 800x600 to whatever is needed or reduce the resolution from photoshop or paint. this should also help

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second part of your question.  Are there any repositories for this type of file (the rptdesign)?

The optimal repository would be the BIRT DevShare http://developer.actuate.com/community/devshare

I searched there and did not find anything. If you wanted to create something and share it.  That would be the best place.

Answer (score 0):

Images will almost always be the worst in terms of file size.  Can you start with non-image SVG representations of the forms?